# SVG Path optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, npm

We have on our project a JSON file made by another team that helped to create dynamic SVG with binding. The problem with the JSON file is it contains duplicate and unoptimized paths.

I've decided to make a NodeJS script that scan the paths contained into the file and that optimize it.

A sample of an unoptimized path:

```
"paths": [ "M59245.1734326687,2320.0L59266.994415716,2320.0L59266.994415716,2320.0L59306.410931336,2320.0L59306.410931336,2320.0L59345.827446956,2320.0L59345.827446956,2320.0L59385.243962576,2320.0L59385.243962576,2320.0L59424.660478196,2320.0L59424.660478196,2320.0L59464.076993816,2320.0L59464.076993816,2320.0L59503.493509436,2320.0L59503.493509436,2320.0L59542.910025056,2320.0L59542.910025056,2320.0L59582.326540676,2320.0L59582.326540676,2320.0L59621.743056296,2320.0L59621.743056296,2320.0L59633.0477129758,2320.0L59633.0477129758,2320.0L59661.159571916,2320.0L59661.159571916,2320.0L59700.576087536,2320.0L59700.576087536,2320.0L59739.992603156,2320.0L59739.992603156,2320.0L59779.409118776,2320.0L59779.409118776,2320.0L59818.825634396,2320.0L59818.825634396,2320.0L59858.242150016,2320.0L59858.242150016,2320.0L59897.658665636,2320.0L59897.658665636,2320.0L59937.075181256,2320.0L59937.075181256,2320.0L59976.491696876,2320.0L59976.491696876,2320.0L60015.908212496,2320.0L60015.908212496,2320.0L60030.5396230941,2320.0L60030.5396230941,2320.0L60055.324728116,2320.0L60055.324728116,2320.0L60094.741243736,2320.0L60094.741243736,2320.0L60134.157759356,2320.0L60134.157759356,2320.0L60173.574274976,2320.0L60173.574274976,2320.0L60212.990790596,2320.0L60212.990790596,2320.0L60252.407306216,2320.0L60252.407306216,2320.0L60291.823821836,2320.0L60291.823821836,2320.0L60331.240337456,2320.0L60331.240337456,2320.0L60370.656853076,2320.0L60370.656853076,2320.0L60410.073368696,2320.0L60410.073368696,2320.0L60428.0157666062,2320.0M60428.0,2320.0L60428.0044472058,2319.99990189987L60428.0044472058,2319.99990189987" ]
```

Path without duplicates (half the length!):

```
"paths": [ "M59245.1734326687,2320L59266.994415716,2320,59306.410931336,2320,59345.827446956,2320,59385.243962576,2320,59424.660478196,2320,59464.076993816,2320,59503.493509436,2320,59542.910025056,2320,59582.326540676,2320,59621.743056296,2320,59633.0477129758,2320,59661.159571916,2320,59700.576087536,2320,59739.992603156,2320,59779.409118776,2320,59818.825634396,2320,59858.242150016,2320,59897.658665636,2320,59937.075181256,2320,59976.491696876,2320,60015.908212496,2320,60030.5396230941,2320,60055.324728116,2320,60094.741243736,2320,60134.157759356,2320,60173.574274976,2320,60212.990790596,2320,60252.407306216,2320,60291.823821836,2320,60331.240337456,2320,60370.656853076,2320,60410.073368696,2320,60428.0157666062,2320M60428,2320L60428.0044472058,2319.99990189987" ]
```

After analyzing results, I've come to a conclusion that I can do simplification of paths to reduce useles lines. So I've decided to do also a simplification of each paths using `npm` package `simplify-path`. It works fine:

```
Not simplified:
[ [ [ 59245.1734326687, 2320 ] ], [ [ 59266.994415716, 2320 ], [ 59306.410931336, 2320 ], [ 59345.827446956, 2320 ], [ 59385.243962576, 2320 ], [ 59424.660478196, 2320 ], [ 59464.076993816, 2320 ], [ 59503.493509436, 2320 ], [ 59542.910025056, 2320 ], [ 59582.326540676, 2320 ], [ 59621.743056296, 2320 ], [ 59633.0477129758, 2320 ], [ 59661.159571916, 2320 ], [ 59700.576087536, 2320 ], [ 59739.992603156, 2320 ], [ 59779.409118776, 2320 ], [ 59818.825634396, 2320 ], [ 59858.242150016, 2320 ], [ 59897.658665636, 2320 ], [ 59937.075181256, 2320 ], [ 59976.491696876, 2320 ], [ 60015.908212496, 2320 ], [ 60030.5396230941, 2320 ], [ 60055.324728116, 2320 ], [ 60094.741243736, 2320 ], [ 60134.157759356, 2320 ], [ 60173.574274976, 2320 ], [ 60212.990790596, 2320 ], [ 60252.407306216, 2320 ], [ 60291.823821836, 2320 ], [ 60331.240337456, 2320 ], [ 60370.656853076, 2320 ], [ 60410.073368696, 2320 ], [ 60428.0157666062, 2320 ] ], [ [ 60428, 2320 ] ], [ [ 60428.0044472058, 2319.99990189987 ] ] ]

Simplified: 
[ 59245.1734326687, 2320, 60428.0044472058, 2319.99990189987 ]
```

How can I convert back to SVG Path the simplified array of points? Is there any API to this?

I drop a part from the code where I simplify SVG Path (except for the RegEx, the code is not from me!):

```
// Parse SVG Path to array.
var commands = pathArrays[i].paths[j].split(/(?=[LMC])/);

// Split the Path array into a Points array.
var pointArrays = commands.map(function(d){
    var pointsArray = d.slice(1, d.length).split(/[\s,-]+/);

    if (pointsArray[0] == '')
        pointsArray.shift();                

    var pairsArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i += 2){
        pairsArray.push([+pointsArray[i], +pointsArray[i+1]]);
    }
    return pairsArray;
});

// Call simplify method from npm package.
var simplifyArray = simplify(pointArrays, 10);

// ==> I want to convert array of points to SVG Path <==
```

Comment: This is a tough one. Just because you have the points "simplified" it would be pretty darn difficult to magically guess what to do with them in how they're meant to be used via the common [SVG Commands](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp). In other words, the things you see as part of the data that start with letters like "M", "L", "Z" etc....are what determines how they're supposed to be used. Just having points is not enough to create the intended image. Sorry amigo.

Comment: The SVG is made of «M» and «L», so I was thinking to recreate the path with something like M[0], L[0], L[1], L[N]...

Comment: Ya I mean if they're all predictable in pattern like that with just planting an "M" at the beginning point, "Z" at the end, and "L" on anything in between that may be do-able. However that assumes there's no curves, horizontal lines, and other points as such outside of the basic pattern. Than ya we could write you up something to consume an array as such if that's the case?

Comment: Yeah there's no curves. I will try something tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Ya if you're literally not doing anything with curves etc, well then you just described a polygon. Which maybe explains why I don't see any commands in the non/simplified examples at the bottom? In which case your task becomes infinitely easier since you don't need to join on commands and just read off the points.

If that's the case, you could do something real simple like this quickie PoC I threw together. Hope it helps, or maybe elaborate more and we'll take another stab. I'm intrigued by the challenge. :)

```js
var geometry = [
  [
    '109,141',
    '59.073,97.825',
    '9.146,54.65',
    '71.5,33',
    '133.854,11.35',
    '121.427,76.175'
  ],
  [
    '133.989,130.188',
    '86.736,114.757',
    '47.501,145.276',
    '47.272,95.175',
    '6.275,66.815',
    '53.385,51.282',
    '67.284,3.237',
    '96.629,43.738',
    '146.216,42.404',
    '117.242,82.968'
  ],
  [
    '8,80',
    '58,144',
    '143,49',
    '127,6',
    '60,112',
    '35,63'
  ]
], 

translate = 0,

create = function() {
    
  for (i=0,r=geometry.length;i<r;i++) {
    
    var polygon = geometry[i].join(),
         colors = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),
          shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");

          shape.setAttribute("points", polygon);
          shape.setAttribute("fill", colors);
          shape.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + translate + ",0)");
    
    translate += 150;
    document.getElementById("shapes").appendChild(shape);   
        
  }
};

create();
```

```html
<svg id="shapes" 
     width="450"
     version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xml:space="preserve">
</svg>
```

....and a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/jLOgVz) to tinker with.

Comment: Great I will give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job:

```
path = 'M' + simplifyArray.join(',');
```